# How to persist a lot of Entities with Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I wrote my first Playground Backend with Quarkus, unfortunetly the persist perfomance of many objects is in my code very bad.

What I do is

```
List<CustomerDto> customerData; // Size 100.000
customerData.parallel().forEach..
 * map to Entity
 * CustomerEntity.persistFlush
```

This takes a lot of time. And looks like very bad code.

What is a good way to store a lot of `List<CustomerDto> customerData;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to increase the performance of bulk inserts using session factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772953/how-to-increase-the-performance-of-bulk-inserts-using-session-factory)

Comment: I don't think persistFlush should be called on each entity, since it is 100 only you can call persist and when loop is finished you call flush method.